PromQL: need to get the increase of counter_a since the last increment of counter_b
I am new to prometheus
I have two counters - counter_a and counter_b. What I want to achieve is using a single PromQL query get the increase of counter_a since the last increment of counter_b. Is that doable?
At first I tried to get the timestamp of the last change of counter_b and calculate the increase using that as a left bound, but that is not possible.
Then I attempted to calculate the increase of counter_a on timeframe where counter_b is equal to it's latest scalar value, but seems like this is not doable as well.

Try something like increase((counter_b and on() counter_a == counter_a @ end())[1d:1s])
